# Fastest way to map images to labels using a csv of image file names + labels

Tags: python, image, performance, lookup

I want to map images (image data arrays) to labels, and the (image names + labels) are in a csv file. The file has both jpg and jpeg file types.
I wrote a simple function to do this, but it is taking quite a while.

Here is my script:

```
def map_data():

    import pandas as pd
    import glob
    import time
    import cv2

    tot_time = time.time()    
    df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
    labeled_set = []

    for f in glob.glob('Processed/*.jp*'):

        try:

            st = time.time()
            img_name = str(f)
            img_data = cv2.imread(f)

            for _,row in df.iterrows():                

                if row['image'] != img_name:
                    continue                
                else:
                    labeled_set.append([img_data, row['label']])

            et = time.time()
            print(str(et-st)+' seconds for one image lookup')

        except Exception as e:

            print(f'{e} occurred, passing')
            pass

    tot_time -= time.time()
    print(str(abs(tot_time)))+' seconds time taken for the mapping')

    return labeled_set
```

Is there a faster way to do this? It would be really helpful to know if there is one. Currently it takes about 25 seconds for one image lookup.

Comment: Why not reverse the logic of looking up? You can iterate over the rows and get the image name and then read the file with image name?

Comment: @MjZac I tried, it was taking longer. I am changing it to leverage Dask now, let's see if it works